# Pandas groupby - dataframe's column disappearing

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame called "new_df":

```
dato    uttak   annlegg Merd    ID  Leng    BW  CF  F   B   H   K
0   2020-12-15  12_20   LL  3   1   48.0    1200    1.085069    0.0 2.0 0.0 NaN
1   2020-12-15  12_20   LL  3   2   43.0    830 1.043933    0.0 1.0 0.0 NaN
```

columns are:

```
'dato', 'uttak', 'annlegg', 'Merd', 'ID', 'Leng', 'BW', 'CF', 'F', 'B', 'H', 'K'
```

when I do:

```
new_df.groupby(['annlegg','Merd'],as_index=False).mean()
```

I got all means except the column "BW" like this:

```
annlegg Merd   ID        Leng         CF           F       B               H        K
0   KH  1   42.557143   56.398649   1.265812    0.071770    1.010638    0.600000    0.127907
1   KH  2   42.683794   56.492228   1.270522    0.021978    0.739130    0.230769    0.075862
2   KH  3   42.177866   35.490119   1.125416    0.000000    0.384146    0.333333    0.034483
```

Column "BW" just disappeared when I groupby, no matter "as_index" True or False, why is that?

Comment: Do you what is the type of the data inside the `BW` column ? Sometimes dataframes store numerial values into string columns and since taking the mean value of a string column does not make sense, the column is dropped when the groupby is aggregated.

Comment: exactly, numerical values are in the column 'BW', but data type shows "object", used the function convert  but it doesn't work

Comment: I have created a detailed answer with two possible options for you, based on your needs / data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the content as the `BW` column does not have a numerical type but an `object` type instead, which is used for storing strings for instance. Thus when applying groupby and `mean`aggregation function, tour column disappears has computing the mean value of an object (think of a string does not make sense *in general*).

You should start by converting your `BW` column :

### First method : **pd.to_numeric**

---

This first method will safely convert all your column to `float` objects.

```py
new_df['BW'] = pd.to_numeric(new_df['BW'])
```

### Second method : **df.astype**

---

If you do not want to convert your data to `float` (for instance, you know that this column only contains int, or if floating point precision does not interest you), you can use the `astype` method which allows you to convert to *almost* any type you want :

```py
new_df['BW'] = new_df['BW'].astype(float)   # Converts to float
new_df['BW'] = new_df['BW'].astype(int)     # Converts to integer
```

You can eventually apply your groupby and aggregation as you did !

Answer (score 0):

That's probably due to the wrong data type. You can try this.

```
new_df = new_df.convert_dtypes()
new_df.groupby(['annlegg','Merd'],as_index=False).mean()
```

You can check dtype via:

```
new_df.dtype
```

Comment: yes, you got the point. the data type is Object for column BW, I tried convert function that you suggested, but it didn't work, and I tried `new_df['BW']=new_df.BW.astype(int) ` also, but didn't work ....

Comment: There may be NAN values try `'Int32'` instead

Comment: erroe shows : name 'Int32' is not defined, but other columns also include NaN values, but their data types are Int64 or float64

Comment: you can use 'Int64' I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can try .agg() function to target specific columns.

```
new_df.groupby(['annlegg','Merd']).agg({'BW':'mean'})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, figured out that the problem was related to its data type. so before it corrected to a numerical data type, no function  works